# Fluent NHibernate: Mapping HasManyToMany by convention

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, conventions, automapping

I'm using Fluent NHibernate's AutoMap feature to map my entities. Most of my entities inherit from a base class `Entity` which has a property `public IList<Tag> Tags`.

The tags are in a separate table in the database, so I use a many-to-many relation. But Fluent NHibernate creates mappings for a one-to-many relation.

I'd like to write a convention to override these mappings to use `HasManyToMany(...)` if the class inherits from `Entity`. Is this possible and how?

The convention could either rely on the property's type or its name.

Some code for illustration:

```
// entities
public class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    // ... some other properties
    public virtual IList<Tag> { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string TagName { get; set; }
}

public class Event : Entity
{
    // ... some properties
}

// Fluent NHibernate configuration
public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    var config = new CustomAutomappingConfiguration();
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Sql")))
        .Mappings(m =>
        {
            m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Event>(config)
                .IgnoreBase<Entity>()
                .Conventions.Add<CustomForeignKeyConvention>()
                .Conventions.Add<CustomManyToManyTableNameConvention>();
        })
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Comment: which inheritance strategy do you use? table-per-concrete-class, table-per-classhirarchy or table-per-subclass?

Comment: I'm not sure, which one this is exactly. Maybe an example can explain: I have `Event : Entity` which maps to the table named 'Event' containing all properties of `Event` and the base class `Entity`.

Comment: this would be table-per-concrete-class. There i only know of `Override<>` for each subclass, which is not what you wanted or heavy use of reflection to call override with the dynamically filtered types

Comment: `Override<>` (or implementations of `IAutoMappingOverride<>`) for each entity is exactly, what I could find so far :-) It works, but I have to remember, when I add another entity. Unfortunately an override of the mapping for `Entity` has no effect... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish the mapping with conventions. However, if you want to keep one linking table between the entities and tags, you can do the following:

```
m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Event>(config)
    .IncludeBase<Entity>()    
    .Override<Entity>(map => 
         map.HasManyToMany(e => e.Tags)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()));
```

Notice that I changed `IgnoreBase<Entity>()` to `IncludeBase<Entity>()`. This will add an Entity table, but will keep one linking table. With this mapping, you will get the following table DDL:

```
create table [Entity] (
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   primary key (Id)
)

create table TagToEntity (
    Entity_id INT not null,
   Tag_id INT not null
)

create table Event (
    Entity_id INT not null,
   primary key (Entity_id)
)

create table [Tag] (
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   TagName NVARCHAR(255) null,
   primary key (Id)
)

alter table TagToEntity 
    add constraint FKD7554554A8C4CA9 
    foreign key (Tag_id) 
    references [Tag]

alter table TagToEntity 
    add constraint FKD75545564C9EC79 
    foreign key (Entity_id) 
    references [Entity]

alter table Event 
    add constraint FKA2FD7DF664C9EC79 
    foreign key (Entity_id) 
    references [Entity]
```

If you choose to do an `Override<>` per subclass, you will have a linking table per subclass.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have an existing database, which I want my entities map to.  I have a linking table for each subclass. As for the `Override<>` for each subclass, that's exactly what I try to avoid :-)

Comment: Sorry...I figured you were trying to avoid that, but thought I would post anyway. Trying to use my solution with an existing db would cause an identity issue. Trying to map with a convention won't work since FNH would not be able to figure out the relationship - Tags would need a collection of Entities (which would fail b/c Entity is unmapped). I'll think on it some more and see if I can come up with something else.

Comment: So you say, what I'd like to do is not possible? What a bummer! :-)
There's no convention to say something like 'if a property is of type IList<Tag> than use a many to many relation'?...possibly

Comment: Like I said, still looking. I've done quite a few convention based mappings and this one is stumping me. >8( Still trying tho.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to use an attribute to indicate a property that should participate in a many-to-many relationship where only one side of the relationship is declared.  You could easily modify this to map by other conventions.

Many-to-many relationships are handled by `FluentNHibernate.Automapping.Steps.HasManyToManyStep`, an `IAutomappingStep` returned by the `DefaultAutomappingConfiguration`.  This step will only map a property if it discovers a corresponding property of the related type (so both ends of the many-to-many relationship have to be declared).

The approach I've taken is to:

- Create a decorator class for `HasManyToManyStep` that supports detecting and mapping many-to-many properties based on the presence of an attribute (or some other convention)
- Create a class derived from `DefaultAutomappingConfiguration` to when [automapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping) and override `GetMappingSteps`, wrapping any instance of `HasManyToManyStep` with the decorator

Here's the decorator, which tries to use the default `HasManyToManyStep` functionality first.  Otherwise, if `HasManyToManyAttribute` is defined for the member, it will also create the relationship.  The code used to create the relationship is nearly identical to the code used by [`HasManyToManyStep`](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Automapping/Steps/HasManyToManyStep.cs) - just without reference to the other side of the relationship.

```
class ExplicitHasManyToManyStep : IAutomappingStep
{
    readonly IAutomappingConfiguration Configuration;
    readonly IAutomappingStep DefaultManyToManyStep;

    public ExplicitHasManyToManyStep(IAutomappingConfiguration configuration, IAutomappingStep defaultManyToManyStep)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        DefaultManyToManyStep = defaultManyToManyStep;
    }

    #region Implementation of IAutomappingStep

    public bool ShouldMap(Member member)
    {
        if (DefaultManyToManyStep.ShouldMap(member))
        {
            return true;
        }

        //modify this statement to check for other attributes or conventions
        return member.MemberInfo.IsDefined(typeof(HasManyToManyAttribute), true);
    }

    public void Map(ClassMappingBase classMap, Member member)
    {
        if (DefaultManyToManyStep.ShouldMap(member))
        {
            DefaultManyToManyStep.Map(classMap, member);
            return;
        }

        var Collection = CreateManyToMany(classMap, member);
        classMap.AddCollection(Collection);
    }

    #endregion

    CollectionMapping CreateManyToMany(ClassMappingBase classMap, Member member)
    {
        var ParentType = classMap.Type;
        var ChildType = member.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        var Collection = CollectionMapping.For(CollectionTypeResolver.Resolve(member));
        Collection.ContainingEntityType = ParentType;
        Collection.Set(x => x.Name, Layer.Defaults, member.Name);
        Collection.Set(x => x.Relationship, Layer.Defaults, CreateManyToMany(member, ParentType, ChildType));
        Collection.Set(x => x.ChildType, Layer.Defaults, ChildType);
        Collection.Member = member;

        SetDefaultAccess(member, Collection);
        SetKey(member, classMap, Collection);
        return Collection;
    }

    void SetDefaultAccess(Member member, CollectionMapping mapping)
    {
        var ResolvedAccess = MemberAccessResolver.Resolve(member);

        if (ResolvedAccess != Access.Property && ResolvedAccess != Access.Unset)
        {
            mapping.Set(x => x.Access, Layer.Defaults, ResolvedAccess.ToString());
        }

        if (member.IsProperty && !member.CanWrite)
        {
            mapping.Set(x => x.Access, Layer.Defaults, Configuration.GetAccessStrategyForReadOnlyProperty(member).ToString());
        }
    }

    static ICollectionRelationshipMapping CreateManyToMany(Member member, Type parentType, Type childType)
    {
        var ColumnMapping = new ColumnMapping();
        ColumnMapping.Set(x => x.Name, Layer.Defaults, childType.Name + "_id");

        var Mapping = new ManyToManyMapping {ContainingEntityType = parentType};
        Mapping.Set(x => x.Class, Layer.Defaults, new FluentNHibernate.MappingModel.TypeReference(childType));
        Mapping.Set(x => x.ParentType, Layer.Defaults, parentType);
        Mapping.Set(x => x.ChildType, Layer.Defaults, childType);
        Mapping.AddColumn(Layer.Defaults, ColumnMapping);

        return Mapping;
    }

    static void SetKey(Member property, ClassMappingBase classMap, CollectionMapping mapping)
    {
        var ColumnName = property.DeclaringType.Name + "_id";
        var ColumnMapping = new ColumnMapping();
        ColumnMapping.Set(x => x.Name, Layer.Defaults, ColumnName);

        var Key = new KeyMapping {ContainingEntityType = classMap.Type};
        Key.AddColumn(Layer.Defaults, ColumnMapping);

        mapping.Set(x => x.Key, Layer.Defaults, Key);
    }
}
```

`HasManyToManyAttribute` class, because there is no other convention I can easily rely on in my case:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class HasManyToManyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Configuration class derived from `DefaultMappingConfiguration` class:

```
class AutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override IEnumerable<IAutomappingStep> GetMappingSteps(AutoMapper mapper, IConventionFinder conventionFinder)
    {
        return base.GetMappingSteps(mapper, conventionFinder).Select(GetDecoratedStep);
    }

    IAutomappingStep GetDecoratedStep(IAutomappingStep step)
    {
        if (step is HasManyToManyStep)
        {
            return new ExplicitHasManyToManyStep(this, step);
        }

        return step;
    }
}
```